# How do I pop two views at once from a navigation controller?

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I want to pop to the third view on the navigation stack back to the first view.

I know how to pop one view at once:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

But how do I do two at once?

Comment: Meta comment: @lubilis answer all the way down there is the best. The top rated answers were good in their time but are no longer relevant.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

You can try this to Jump between the navigation controller stack as well

```
NSMutableArray *allViewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.navigationController viewControllers]];
for (UIViewController *aViewController in allViewControllers) {
    if ([aViewController isKindOfClass:[RequiredViewController class]]) {
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:aViewController animated:NO];
    }
}
```

Comment: imo this is the best method by far , but you should reference your uinavigation controller using self.navigationcontroller

Comment: I agree, this is the best solution if the user would like to pop the stack back to a certain viewcontroller. Let's say you don't know which viewcontroller that is, you can still implement a system where you would specify how many viewcontrollers you would like to pop off the stack and get the target viewcontroller from the allViewControllers array with objectAtIndex:(allViewControllers.count - 1 - amount). -1 because arrays are zero-based ofcourse.

Comment: Works also when iterating over the original navigator->viewControllers array (no need converting it to a mutable array)

Comment: NOTE! That this will iterate the stack from the beginning -> to the end, to be exactly correct you should reverse the stack. Because if you have several VC's of the same kind you will remove the wrong VC in the wrong order in the stack.

Answer (score 80):

Here are two `UINavigationController` extensions that can solve your problem. I would recommend using the first one that pops to a `UIViewController` of a specific class:

```
extension UINavigationController {

  func popToViewController(ofClass: AnyClass, animated: Bool = true) {
    if let vc = viewControllers.filter({$0.isKind(of: ofClass)}).last {
      popToViewController(vc, animated: animated)
    }
  }

  func popViewControllers(viewsToPop: Int, animated: Bool = true) {
    if viewControllers.count > viewsToPop {
      let vc = viewControllers[viewControllers.count - viewsToPop - 1]
      popToViewController(vc, animated: animated)
    }
  }

}
```

and use it like this:

```
// pop to SomeViewController class
navigationController?.popToViewController(ofClass: SomeViewController.self)

// pop 2 view controllers
navigationController?.popViewControllers(viewsToPop: 2)
```

Comment: For Swift (option 1), you can replace the two `removeLast` with just `removeLast(2)`.

Comment: What about calling methods of controllers's lifecycle? DidAppear and ect

Comment: (Swift 4) You missing brackets in this line `let vc = viewControllers[viewControllers.count - viewsToPop + 1]`, in order to work correctly you need to replace it with: `let vc = viewControllers[viewControllers.count - (viewsToPop + 1)]` or `let vc = viewControllers[viewControllers.count - viewsToPop - 1]`

Comment: @MMiroslav your are right. I've updated my answer. Thank you / Hvala ;)

Comment: This answer has been updated after I posted my answer below. Essentially a copy of my code ^_^

Comment: @lubilis I've been updating and maintaining this answer since the first time I've posted it in 2014. I even left a comment on your answer and wrote how it inspired me to improve my answer and what I did differently.

Answer (score 46):

You can pop to the "root" (first) view controller with `popToRootViewControllerAnimated`:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

// If you want to know what view controllers were popd:
// NSArray *popdViewControllers = [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

[`UINavigationController` Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Pops all the view controllers on the stack except the root view controller and updates the display.
>
> **Return Value**
>   An array of view controllers that are popped from the stack.

Comment: ha, can't believe I spent so long looking for such a simple answer, thanks!

Comment: Swift 3: self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated:true);

Comment: Precisely what I was looking for!

Answer (score 29):

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];
```

objectAtIndex:1 --> you can pass whichever index you want to pop to

Comment: Thanks for the trick, I was just about to doing it the wrong way.

Answer (score 19):

Swift 2 - xCode 7.3

This could be a very useful extension to pop UIViewControllers:

```
extension UINavigationController {

    func popToViewControllerOfType(classForCoder: AnyClass) {
        for controller in viewControllers {
            if controller.classForCoder == classForCoder {
                popToViewController(controller, animated: true)
                break
            }
        }
    }

    func popViewControllers(controllersToPop: Int, animated: Bool) {
        if viewControllers.count > controllersToPop {
            popToViewController(viewControllers[viewControllers.count - (controllersToPop + 1)], animated: animated)
        } else {
            print("Trying to pop \(controllersToPop) view controllers but navigation controller contains only \(viewControllers.count) controllers in stack")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This needs more upvoting.. .I was just about to write that extension. I'll just use yours thanks ;)

Comment: @n13 how come this is better than budidino's answer?

Comment: Using an extension makes for much cleaner code. You could take budidino's answer and make an extension out of it but this one saves you the effort. Also this answer checks for error cases, and handles errors gracefully (e.g. trying to pop more than you have)

Comment: I like this answer. Made me rethink and update the answer I posted. I made my code pop to the last instance of the searched class in the viewControllers array because that is probably the desired behavior.

Answer (score 15):

If you just want to pop 2 at once because your rootViewController is (way) 'deeper' then 2 you could consider adding a category to UIviewController for example:

#### UINavigationController+popTwice.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface UINavigationController (popTwice)

- (void) popTwoViewControllersAnimated:(BOOL)animated;

@end
```

#### UINavigationController+popTwice.m

```
#import "UINavigationController+popTwice.h"

@implementation UINavigationController (popTwice)

- (void) popTwoViewControllersAnimated:(BOOL)animated{
    [self popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [self popViewControllerAnimated:animated];
}

@end
```

Import the category `#import "UINavigationController+popTwice.h"` somewhere in your implementation and use this line of code to pop 2 controllers at once:

```
[self.navigationController popTwoViewControllersAnimated:YES];
```

isn't that great? :)

Comment: what if you need to pop three view, you'll write "UINavigationController+popThrice.m"??????

Comment: you could just pass in a parameter for the number of viewControllers to pop, and wrap

    [self popViewControllerAnimated:NO];

within a for-loop, of count-1.

Comment: This is not the correct way, if you want to pot to 2,3,...any controller identify it by loop and then use [self.navigationController popToViewControllerAnimated:YES];. This above mentioned is very bad coding and may show flickered UI and bad user experience.

Answer (score 13):

> **Swift 4 :**

```
func popViewControllerss(popViews: Int, animated: Bool = true) {
    if self.navigationController!.viewControllers.count > popViews
    {
        let vc = self.navigationController!.viewControllers[self.navigationController!.viewControllers.count - popViews - 1]
         self.navigationController?.popToViewController(vc, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

Then Use This Method

```
self.popViewControllerss(popViews: 2)
```

Comment: Good one, What i was looking for. Thank u.

Answer (score 6):

You can also try this one :-

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:yourViewController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 6):

```
//viewIndex = 1;
//viewIndex = 2;
//viewIndex = 3;

// **[viewControllers objectAtIndex: *put here your viewindex number*]

NSArray *viewControllers = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[viewControllers objectAtIndex:viewIndex] animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    NSMutableArray *newStack = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.navigationController viewControllers]];
    [newStack removeLastObject];
    [newStack removeLastObject];
    [self.navigationController setViewControllers:newStack animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 4):

**In Swift 3**,
you can pop one, two or more viewcontrollers from navigation controller like that

```
let viewControllers = self.navigationController!.viewControllers as [UIViewController]
    for aViewController:UIViewController in viewControllers {
        if aViewController.isKind(of: FromWhereYouWantToGoController.self) {
            _ = self.navigationController?.popToViewController(aViewController, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

Here FromWhereYouWantToGoController is destination controller. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the initial view controller (the one you want to come back to) and then call this line in the last view:

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:yourInitialViewController animated:YES];
```

L.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't see this answer in here. If you only want to pop a few (not all the way to the root), you can just iterate through self.navigationController.viewControllers checking for class types, or if you have a reference use that:

```
for (UIViewController *aViewController in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {
   if ([aViewController isKindOfClass:[SMThumbnailViewController class]]) {
      [self.navigationController popToViewController:aViewController animated:YES];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can pop back to the root view controller

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

or, if the view you want to pop to isn't the first one, you'll need to pop again in your previous view's viewWillAppear

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little function I'm using to go back X ViewControllers:

```
-(void)backMultiple:(id)data {
    int back = 2; //Default to go back 2 
    int count = [self.navigationController.viewControllers count];

    if(data[@"count"]) back = [data[@"count"] intValue];

    //If we want to go back more than those that actually exist, just go to the root
    if(back+1 > count) {
        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
    //Otherwise go back X ViewControllers 
    else {
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:count-(back+1)] animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift Version as of (Swift 1.2 / Xcode 6.3.1)
of popping twice or more

```
 var viewControllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers
 viewControllers?.removeLast()
 viewControllers?.removeLast()
 self.navigationController?.setViewControllers(viewControllers, animated: true)
```

or

```
 var viewControllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers
 var viewsToPop = 2
 var end = (viewControllers?.count)!
 var start = end - viewsToPop
 viewControllers?.removeRange(Range<Int>(start: start, end: end))
 self.navigationController?.setViewControllers(viewControllers, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can use the stack of the UIViewControllers.
 1. Fetch the array of all the viewControllers in the stack.
 2. Iterate through the whole array and find the desired viewController

    by matching the class type.
 3. Pop the viewController.**

```
func popToSpecificViewC
{
let viewControllers: [UIViewController] = self.navigationController!.viewControllers as [UIViewController];
        for viewController:UIViewController in viewControllers
        {
            if viewController.isKind(of: WelcomeViewC.self)
            {
                _ = self.navigationController?.popToViewController(viewController, animated: true)
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple ***UINavigationController extension***:

```
extension UINavigationController {
    func popViewControllers(_ count: Int) {
        guard viewControllers.count > count else { return }
        popToViewController(viewControllers[viewControllers.count - count - 1], animated: true)
    }
}
```