# How to Pop stack in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller

I am building an iOS application.

What I am doing is explained below -

1. There are 3 ViewControllers named as A, B, C.
2. I go to A to B and then to C on button click function.
3. I have to Implement Navigation controller on all three ViewController (A, B, C).
4. Now, when I press back of navigation controller the stack that is followed is C -> B -> A. This is the default behavior.

What I need is the stack operation should be perform like - C -> A.

For this I have to Pop B from the stack. How can I Pop the B from stack.

Comment: You can use function `- (NSArray *)popToRootViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated`

Comment: @hiteshmatnani [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES] just write this line. it will help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return to root view in IOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035320/return-to-root-view-in-ios)

Comment: you can use unwind segue to pop multiple view's back. see the answer

Answer (score 4):

If your intention is to always go back to the first view controller on the stack, you can use

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

If you want to pop `X` number of view controllers, check this answer from SO: [How do I pop two views at once from a navigation controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236940/how-do-i-pop-two-views-at-once-from-a-navigation-controller)

Answer (score 0):

use below code to do this

```
NSArray *viewContrlls=[[self navigationController] viewControllers];
for( int i=0;i<[ viewContrlls count];i++){
  id obj=[viewContrlls objectAtIndex:i];
  if([obj isKindOfClass:[A class]]){
    // A is your class where to popback
    [[self navigationController] popToViewController:obj animated:YES];
    return;
    }
  }
```