# UIViewController how to jump to grandparent view?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

[image]

I have 3 views called A,B and C. The segue between them is "present modally". `dismissViewControllerAnimated` can be used to jump back to parent view controller, but does it have a way to jump from C to A directly?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30304026/how-to-pop-stack-in-ios/30304177

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a storyboard, you can use an **unwind segue** to back up multiple steps in a view controller hierarchy.

1. Define a method on view controller A of the form `- (IBAction)unwind:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue`. It needs to take a segue as the argument, not just any `id` sender.
2. Hook up a segue action from view controller C to the exit proxy in the white bar above the controller's view. You should see a menu pop up with a list of unwind segue selectors; pick the one you defined earlier.

Unwind segues work by walking the parent and presenting view controller hierarchy until they find a controller that implements the chosen method. You don't have to put any code in this method; just to have it exist with an empty body is enough. Once the storyboard finds such a method, it will pop and dismiss view controllers until it reveals the one that implements that method.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to directly jump to A and A is you rootViewcontroller then you can use this code in you C controller

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

but if you want to pass a certain data from C controller to A controller then you have to use Segue 
these all are mentioned in navigationController class
refer to : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html

Answer (score 1):

Use Navigation stack for Push and Pop ViewControllers, and if you need to present and dismiss viewController then , you can try with UIAnimation with Navigation Push and Pop stack,

And then you can easily navigate to Parent ViewController with below Code.

[self.navigationController popToViewController:self.navigationController.viewControllers[self.navigationController.viewControllers.count - 3]  animated:YES];

Hope , this may help you. !!!!!

Comment: I had used unwind segue but your answer demonstrates a really good way,  thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[UINavigationController_Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/)

[popToViewController:animated:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/popToViewController:animated:)

**Objective - C**

```
   UIViewController *prevVC = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:IndexViewOfA];
    //you get index of view (A,B,C) from array self.navigationController.viewControllers
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:prevVC animated:YES];
```

[popTOViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753256/poptoviewcontroller)

This might helps you :)