# UINavigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated goes back one by one

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, viewwilldisappear

This is the simple code I am calling to go back to `rootViewController` of `UINavigationController` :

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
     [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];   
     [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

But the back navigation occurs one by one.
Say I have 3 viewControllers - **A, B, C**.
**A -> B -> C**
What I want on back of C is :
**C -> A**
But on using popToRootViewControllerAnimated, this is how back navigation appears :
**C -> B -> A**

Comment: you should call [super viewWillDisappear:animted] before you do anything else.

Comment: see this link may be heps you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236940/how-do-i-pop-two-views-at-once-from-a-navigation-controller

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:VC animated:YES]
```

instead of

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

wrap this in a category and add your logic to make it more modular. You can jump to any view controller.

Another way of doing is that swizzling `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` which I think you should definitely avoid since this is a general method used heavily app-wise. You can modify it's actual behavior with your swizzled behavior.

See http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/ for swizzling.

Answer (score 0):

Try to realize what should happen

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
  {
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

  }
```

1st you calling **viewWillDisappear** method. which will execute first. after executing this Your current view is "**B**". Then executes "**[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]**" 
so. you will see **A<-B** (view A backed from B)

so, you will see in all **A<-B<-C**.

To resolve this issue try to execute **popToRootViewControllerAnimated**  method outside **viewWillDisappear** method