# viewWillAppear not called after popToViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, viewwillappear, poptoviewcontroller

I have a little problem.
I am working on a simple application with Views Controllers in a Navigation Controller like this:
A->B->C (-> are modal segues)
View A is the Root View Controller and I need to come back to A from C. If I call the method popToViewController from B, A run the viewWillAppear; if I call the popToViewController from C (to A), viewWillAppear on A is not called.
How can I solve this? (Working on Xcode7 and iOS 9)

**ViewController A**

```
#import "ViewControllerA.h"
#import "ViewControllerB.h"

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self setupSceneA];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"goToB"]) {
       ViewControllerB *b = [segue destinationViewController];
    }
}
```

**ViewController B**

```
#import "ViewControllerB.h"
#import "ViewControllerC.h"

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self setupSceneB];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"goToC"]) {
       ViewControllerC *c = [segue destinationViewController];
    }
}

- (IBAction)backToAButton:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

**ViewController C**

```
#import "ViewControllerC.h";

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self setupSceneC];
}


- (IBAction)backToBButton:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)backToAButton:(id)sender {
    [[self parentViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: So do you use modal or push segues? There is a difference. It seems like you're speaking about push segue.

Comment: If you're using modal segues, you need to use dismiss view controller.

Comment: I am using modal segues and I use dismiss view controller soon after the popToViewController. When I am on B it's ok but when I'm on C it calls A without running viewWillAppear.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This should be your design:

Controller A -> modal segue to Nav Controller(Controller B is root view controller) -> push segue to controller C.

So if you want to come from C to B, you do a pop.

When you want to come from B to A or from C to A, you do a dismiss.

Answer (score 1):

If you implement one of these two **CASES** provided below you will definitely get `viewWillAppear` and be sure you wrote it correct with it's `super`

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    // Your code goes here
}
```

**CASE 1 - Using Navigation Controller**

If you want to Pop from one ViewController to another you need to have all of them in the same navigation stack. It means every time you want to **open new View Controller** you need to do something like this:

```
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextVC animated:YES];
```

**instead of doing this**

```
[self presentViewController:nextVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And after that if you already have all VCs in that same Navigation Controller, you can use this code to **go one step back** (e.g. from B to A, from C to B)

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

And you can use this code to **jump to the beginning** (e.g. from C to A)

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

**CASE 2 - Usual Cycle (Looks like what you need)**

This is en easy case but you need to be more careful with your code. You can just get parent of the parent to Leave current View Controller

[[[self presentingViewController] presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

*Note: You can't use navigation controller functions with modal presentation functions. Push is with Pop, Present is with Dismiss*

---

**UPDATE 1**

Modal segues is creating a nested connection(one line of a tree). If you close child(current) VC parent VC appears normally. If you want to jump to the parent of the parent just dismiss the parent and it will dismiss all it's child VCs. I don't know why popViewControllerAnimated works fine from B to A but you are not allowed to do like that. Just use dismiss if if you are using modal segues. Never use Pop. Pop is for Push. Do this and everything should work fine.

For going back from B to A change your code to:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

For going back from C to A use this code:

```
[[self parentViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

**OR**

```
[[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

I discovered that for STORYBOARD segues we NEED to use this code to go back

```
[[[self presentingViewController] presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

This code totally fine jumps from **C to A** and `viewWillAppear` is being called BUT `viewWillAppear` is being called both in **A and B**

You have 3 tracks to choose (Actually you have more, like using delegates and notifications but this is too bad)

1. Stick to this version but it is not reliable.
2. Keep using storyboard but for using backCtoA button connect with A from VC C so it always loops but loads again every time. Bad but still ok.
3. Finally the right solution is to move to Navigation Controllers(btw. you can hide Nav Bar if you want) and have VCs Stack so you can easily use popToViewController

Comment: But B and C are both modal. Why if I use Pop from B to A does it works? If I need to go back from C to A and get the viewWillAppear of A I have to implement the second case? And I have to implement this in A or in C?

Comment: @AngeloPettinelli your cycle goes like this: A loads then from A you go to B then from B you go to C and then from C you want to jump back to A, right?

Comment: Yes. I need to go to A both from B and C. I used for both the popToRootViewController but from B it works, from C no

Comment: @AngeloPettinelli Please check UPDATE 1

Comment: [[self parentViewController]...] does nothing... remain on C.

Comment: [[self presentingViewController]...] come back to B

Comment: @AngeloPettinelli please provide your source files so I can see whats wrong there

Comment: for going back from B to A I changed my code and works the same perfectly. The problem of going from C to A still remains :/

Comment: @AngeloPettinelli I added Update two and you can see al possible versions you have.

Comment: Do you mean adding to navigation controller as push segues?

Comment: @AngeloPettinelli [self.navigationController pushViewController:vcB animated:NO]; do pushes in code, segues are way too slow. Then use this answer to pop 2 views back http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236940/how-do-i-pop-two-views-at-once-from-a-navigation-controller